Use "literal" device pixels in CSS styling
On a device with a high DPI monitor, I like the way the following CSS styles
links on my page:
a {
  text-decoration: underline solid currentcolor 0.5px;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline solid currentcolor 1px;
}

Because the device scaling factor is 2, this renders the underline below the
link with a thickness of 1 literal pixel normally and 2 literal pixels
when hovered.
However, on a normal 1080p monitor, 0.5px rounds up to 1 literal pixel, and
hovering has no visual effect.
Instead, I want to make a CSS rule that says, "Display the underline as the
thinnest displayable thickness by default, and make it 1 device pixel thicker
when hovered." Is this possible?

My question is distinct from this question about "viewport pixels"—a concept that, as the answer there suggests, does not even exist. That post is seven years out of date, and CSS has grown considerably since then, including adding many more units. Moreover, even if the "device pixel" unit doesn't exist, there may be another way to achieve the effect I am seeking (namely, differentiating two levels of underline by the smallest possible amount).
